# Decode Html-encoded characters during Json deserialization

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net, html-encode

I’m using Json.net to deserialize json data received by Web API call. Some fields often have html-encoded characters like `&quot;` or `&amp;` How can I have this characters automatically decoded during deserialization?

I came to 2 possible solutions:

1. Calling `System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode()` in property setter like:

   ```
   public string Title
   {
       set
       {
           title = System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(value);
       }
   }
   ```
2. Writing custom JsonConverter that calls `System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode()` in `ReadJson()` method:

   ```
   public class HtmlEncodingConverter : Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConverter
   {
       public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
       {
           return objectType == typeof(String);
       }

       public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
       {
           return System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode((string)reader.Value);
       }

       public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
       {
           writer.WriteRawValue(System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode((string)value));
       }
   }
   ```

But is there any built-in solution that allows to perform html-decoding during json deserialization without additional code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode()
```

or

```
HttpUtility.HtmlDecode()
```

is the way to go, nothing built in regarding the JsonSerializer.